# How to close kendo ui drop down menu by hitting the ESC key?

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, dropdown

How to close kendo ui drop down menu by hitting the ESC key?

```
$(detailsRightMenu).kendoDropDownList();
$(detailsRightMenu).parent().on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 27 ) {
          $('detailsRightMenu', this).data("kendoDropDownList").close();
    }
});
```

Comment: I test the component here and it's out of the box working with the esc key. please check https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

Comment: If you want to use the events please refer to https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events there is a close event that you can use if needed